# Why does my Azure Function to write to MongoDB Atlas have >70s cold start time?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, azure-functions, mongodb-atlas

I wonder whether there is a general problem in my function, which leads to such a long cold start. Mongoose has been installed as a dependency which might increase the time. But 70s?!? Come on...

Here is my code. Quite simple really. Just wanna write some stuff to MongoDB. I appreciate any feedback.

```js
module.exports = function(context, req) {
  context.log("Function started!");

  // Database interaction.
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const DATABASE = process.env.MongodbAtlas;

  // Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
  mongoose.connect(DATABASE);
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    context.log(`ERROR→ ${err.message}`);
  });

  // Portfolio Schema.
  require('./portfolioModel');
  const Portfolio = mongoose.model('Portfolio');

  //Create a Portfolio object.
  var portfolio = new Portfolio();
  portfolio.fiat = "EUR";
  portfolio.token[0] = {
    crypto_ticker: "BTC",
    crypto_name: "Bitcoin",
    crypto_qty: 50,
    crypto_invested_sum: 9000
  };

  // Save to db.
  portfolio.save();
  context.done();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cold start time was reduced to around 3s once I used the [Azure Functions extension for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started). The extension is automatically creating a package file and sets WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 ([some in-depth infos regarding packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package)).

Now "Functions as a Service" gets a lot more interesting.